# How can I store a serialized object inside a database table in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, blob

I am trying to store a serialized object into my database table in Laravel. I want to save it as a LONGBLOB however, Laravel does not support this in blue prints and only allows me to save as a `binary()` which is the [BLOB equivalent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations).

Inside my migration, it looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('platforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('user_id');

        $table->string('name');

        $table->binary('classifier');

        $table->integer('steps')
              ->default(10000);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I try to then save my serialized object to the database like so:

```
protected function storeClassifier($blob, $ainame) {
    DB::table('platforms')->insert(
        [
            'user_id'       => \Auth::user()->id,
            'name'          => $ainame,
            'classifier'    => $blob
        ]
    );
}
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'classifier' at row 1

How can I create a LONGBLOB column for classifier inside my migration? The full object serialized [looks like this](https://pastebin.com/tnwWMK57) (extremely big).

Comment: Would LONGTEXT be a viable option? Laravel migrations support that.

Comment: @Jaquarh Your data is being serialized as a string, it says so right at the beginning. I'm fairly confident LONGTEXT will do the job.

Comment: Cancel last, I removed the `$table->binary('classifier')` from my Schema, added the `DB::statement()` beneath the Schema and this worked! Thanks @aynber

Comment: Thanks for your comments @jszobody this may have worked!